# Redirection php not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

i tried to redirrect from link.com/signature.php?user=UserName to link.com/singature/UserName.

I used this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+signature(?:\.php)?\?user=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ signature/%1? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^signature/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ signature.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But, redirrects me to link.com/signature/UserName, but the server shows me error 505:

"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /signature.php?user=$1 [L]
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /signature(?:\.php)?\?user=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /signature/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^signature/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ signature.php?user=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Works, but the script can't find the user in database, if he has . last characther in his name.

Comment: rewrite rules can't query your database. That condition needs to be handled within your php code.

Comment: Then continue using your script if it was working fine for you. Since you haven't shown your script only you can figure out that.